# suggestName for IO(Vec(...))

Tags: chisel

I have a module like so...

```
class ApbSplitter (clients : List[ApbRange]) extends MultiIOModule {
  val nApb = clients.length

  val apb   = IO(Vec(nApb, new ApbChannel()))
  val apb_m = IO(Flipped(new ApbChannel))
  ...
```

What I'd like to do is suggestName to each element of the Vec so that instead of prefixed as `apb_0_` `apb_1_` etc... it's whatever I provide for each element.

I can `apb.suggestName` but that only affects the leading prefix and the array indices remain.  Doing `apb(idx).suggestName("blah")` compiles but has no effect.

Any way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this with Brian's [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68750142/exception-connecting-vec-of-io/) and comment on his own answer on this post in mind. This is going to be a long answer because it touches on a couple of warts in the Chisel API that are being improved but are certainly relevant in the current version (v3.4.3 as of 12 Aug 2021).

Brian's answer is correct that if you want to name the individual fields you need to use a `Seq` and not a `Vec`. The reason for this is that, from Chisel's perspective, an `IO` of type `Vec` is a single port with an aggregate type, whereas the `Seq` is just a sequence of unrelated ports. The `Seq` is a Scala construct (whereas `Vec` comes from Chisel), so Chisel itself doesn't know anything about the relationship between the ports in the `Seq`.

The problem then, is that you need a `Vec` to do dynamic indexing. You can use `VecInit` to create a dynamically indexable `Wire` from your `Seq` whenever you need to do dynamic indexing:

[For example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/RYu5gtwsTHqQWKSfVn2UkQ):

```scala
class MyModule(names: Seq[String]) extends RawModule {
  val enq = names.map(n => IO(Flipped(Decoupled(UInt(8.W)))).suggestName(n))
  val idx = IO(Input(UInt(log2Ceil(names.size).W)))
  val deq = IO(Decoupled(UInt(8.W)))
 
  // enqWire connects all fields of enq
  val enqWire = VecInit(enq)
  // Need to make sure backpressure is always driven
  enqWire.foreach(_.ready := false.B)
  deq <> enqWire(idx)
}
```

This will work so long as `deq` is itself a port. It will **not** work if `deq` were a Wire because `<>` is a commutative operator and is thus ambiguous when connecting 2 bidirectional wires. For a longer explanation, see [this PR comment](https://github.com/chipsalliance/chisel3/pull/2065#discussion_r687985734).

If `deq` needs to be a `Wire` for some reason, you could use a helper module that *does* have Vecs as ports:

[For example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/6548PPGWQ0mLnMAwolsvQw):

```scala
class InnerHelper(n: Int) extends RawModule {
  val enq = IO(Flipped(Vec(n, Decoupled(UInt(8.W)))))
  val idx = IO(Input(UInt(log2Ceil(n).W)))
  val jdx = IO(Input(UInt(log2Ceil(n).W)))
  val deq = IO(Vec(n, Decoupled(UInt(8.W))))
  
  // backpressure defaults
  enq.foreach(_.ready := false.B)
  deq.foreach { x =>
    x.valid := false.B
    x.bits := DontCare
  }
  
  deq(jdx) <> enq(idx)
}

class MyModule(names: Seq[String]) extends RawModule {
  val enq = names.map(n => IO(Flipped(Decoupled(UInt(8.W)))).suggestName(n))
  val idx = IO(Input(UInt(log2Ceil(names.size).W)))
  val jdx = IO(Input(UInt(log2Ceil(names.size).W)))
  val deq = names.map(n => IO(Decoupled(UInt(8.W))).suggestName(s"${n}_out"))
  
  val helper = Module(new InnerHelper(names.size))
  helper.enq <> enq
  helper.idx := idx
  helper.jdx := jdx
  helper.deq <> deq
}
```

It's a bit of a pain, but it at least resolves the ambiguity. There are other utilities we could build--for example, instead of a custom `InnerHelper` for each case, we could make a utility method that creates a module so that the returned value of dynamically indexing a `Seq` is a port of a new submodule, but it's a bit tricky.

The good news is that a better way is coming--[DataView](https://github.com/chipsalliance/chisel3/pull/1955) in Chisel 3.5 should make it possible to *view* a `Seq` as a `Vec` (rather than having to use `VecInit` which creates a `Wire`) which makes it easier to avoid this `Wire` `<>` connect ambiguity issue. I also hope to either "fix" `<>` for Wires or perhaps provide a new operator that is not commutative `:<>`, but that is not yet being worked on.

Comment: Yup - That did the trick!  Of course now I've got multiple calls to emitVerilog with various flavors of this and need to uniquify the instances of InnerModule somehow.

Comment: If the types are different, they won't Dedup. You could use `InlineInstance` will make sure those helpers get inlined and thus those modules won't show up in the Verilog: https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/latest/chisel3/util/experimental/InlineInstance.html

Answer (score 2):

Got this to work by eliminating the Vec and creating a list of IO

```
case class ApbRange (name: String, loAddr : Int, hiAddr : Int)

class ApbSplitter (clients : List[ApbRange]) extends MultiIOModule {
  val apb = clients.map({x => IO(new ApbChannel).suggestName(x.name)})
  val apb_m = IO(Flipped(new ApbChannel))
  ...
```

Not sure if this is canonical but seems to do the trick just fine.

Comment: Unaccepted my answer since if you actually need to access the elements of `apb` as a Vec (vs Seq, as I do) this method breaks down.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your new apbChannel has a bunch of Input Output signals or wires. So instead of apb(idx).suggestName if your apbChannel has a (say) `val ip = Input(Bool())` you can do `apb(idx).ip.suggestName("blah")`

Comment: Sadly no - this doesn't have any effect either.  The naming seems fixed by the Vec wrapping the Bundle.

Comment: Try doing this val ip = Input(Bool()).suggestName("blah")

Comment: Also no, and this would override the 'inner' name anyway rather than the 'outer' name pre-peneded by the Vec whcih is what I'm after.