# Exception connecting Vec of IO

Tags: chisel

Can anyone explain what the problem with this construction is?  I have a child module with a Vec of IO that I'm trying to attach to the equivilent IO in the parent module.

This works out fine with just a Seq but I get an exception during elaboration when wrapped up in Vec.  The Vec is needed since in my real case that gets indexed with a hardware signal in the child module.

The error:

```
[error] chisel3.internal.ChiselException: Connection between left (MyBundle[3](Wire in Lower)) and source (MyBundle[3](Wire in Upper)) failed @(0).out: Left or Right unavailable to current module.
```

The code:

```
package Testcase

import chisel3._
import chisel3.util._
import chisel3.stage.ChiselStage

import amba._

class MyBundle extends Bundle {
  val out = Output(UInt(32.W))
}

class Upper (n : Int) extends RawModule {
  val io = VecInit(Seq.fill(n)(IO(new MyBundle)))
  val lower = Module(new Lower(n))

  // This should word in the Vec case but gets the same error
  // lower.io <> io

  // This works for non Vec case
  (lower.io, io).zipped map (_ <> _)
}


class Lower (n : Int) extends RawModule {
  val io = VecInit(Seq.fill(n)(IO(new MyBundle)))

  for (i <- 0 to n - 1) {
    io(i).out := 0.U
  }
}

object VerilogMain extends App {
  (new ChiselStage).emitVerilog(new Upper(3), Array("--target-dir", "generated"))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `VecInit` creates a `Wire` of type `Vec` and connects everything in the `Seq` to the elements of that `Wire`. What you're basically doing is creating a `Seq` of `IOs` and then connecting them to a `Wire`.

This is mentioned in the error message (eg. `(MyBundle[3](Wire in Lower))`) but I totally see the confusion--it's not all that clear and `VecInit` is probably misnamed. This particular ambiguity in the API comes from historical design decisions in Chisel that are slowly getting fixed but it is a wart that sometimes bites users, sorry about that.

Here's the right way to accomplish what you want, just using `IO(Vec(<n>, <type>))`. `Vec(<n>, <type>)` is the way to create something of type `Vec`, in this case an `IO` of type `Vec`, as opposed to creating a `Wire` and connecting all of the fields:

```scala
class Upper (n : Int) extends RawModule {
  //val io = VecInit(Seq.fill(n)(IO(new MyBundle)))
  val io = IO(Vec(n, new MyBundle))
  val lower = Module(new Lower(n))

  // This should word in the Vec case but gets the same error
  lower.io <> io
  
}


class Lower (n : Int) extends RawModule {
  //val io = VecInit(Seq.fill(n)(IO(new MyBundle)))
  val io = IO(Vec(n, new MyBundle))

  for (i <- 0 to n - 1) {
    io(i).out := 0.U
  }
}
```

(Scastie link: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/COb88oXGRmKQb7BZ3id9gg)

Comment: Thanks Jack.  That makes sense.  I perhaps over simplified the testcase since the reason I ended up at VecInit is that I already had a Seq that I was trying to convert to a Vec.   val apb = VecInit(clients.map({x => IO(new ApbChannel).suggestName(x.name)})).  What's the preferred way of doing that?

Comment: Marking this accepted since it does fix the problem.  If you have the time please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/67387506/1795592 which deals with getting suggestName to work on individual elements of of IO(Vec()).  Thanks again.

Comment: You probably got a notification but I have responded there https://stackoverflow.com/a/68762881/2483329